# C++11: when move ctor/operator= is called?

Tags: c++, c++11

```
#include <iostream>

class Class
{
    public:
    Class() { std::cerr << "ctor" << std::endl; }
    ~Class() { std::cerr <<"dtor" << std::endl; }

    Class(Class&)  { std::cerr << "copy ctor" << std::endl; }
    Class & operator=(const Class &)
    {
            std::cerr << "copy operator=" << std::endl;
            return *this;
    }

    Class(Class&&) { std::cerr << "move ctor" << std::endl;}
    Class & operator=(Class &&)
    {       
            std::cerr << "move operator="<< std::endl;
            return *this;
    }
 };

int main(int, char**)
{
    Class object;
    Class && rvr = Class(); 
    object = rvr; // (*)
}
```

Output is

```
ctor
ctor
copy operator=
dtor
dtor
```

1) Why "copy ctor" is called at line (*)?

2) If i have to use std::move() every-time, what is the difference between "move semantics" and any method that will move data, like `object.destructive_move();`?

3) when exactly move ctor/operator is called?

thanks!

Answer (score 7):

The copy ctor is not called at line (*), the copy assignment operator is called. I guess that's what you meant.

It is the copy assignment operator that is called rather than the move assignment operator since `rvr` is an lvalue. Note that the type of an expression is orthogonal to whether it's an lvalue or not.

If you modified your assignment statement to `object = Class();` or even `object = static_cast<Class&&>(rvr)`, you would find the move assignment operator being called, since the RHS is an rvalue in those two cases.

This behavior is sensible: consider the implementation of a move assignment operator, say. Its parameter has type rvalue reference, but it is still an lvalue. If it were an rvalue, then the first use of the parameter could modify its state to become an 'empty' object (move semantics), and then a second use of the parameter would probably not work as expected.

The way it actually works, you would explicitly use `std::move` when you wanted to use the parameter in a way that left it an 'empty' state.

Comment: `static_cast<Class&&>(rvr)` -- this is funny to me... `rvr` is already `Class&&`

Comment: @user1494506: Yes, the cast does not change its type, I'm merely making use of a side-effect that its result is an rvalue (specifically, an xvalue).

Comment: @user1494506: the introduction of rvalue references required the C++ committee to refine the old classification of 'lvalue' vs 'rvalue'. There are now three basic categories: 'lvalue', 'xvalue' and 'prvalue' (pure rvalue). The first two are collectively referred to as 'glvalue' (generalized lvalue), the last two are collectively refereed to as 'rvalue'.

Comment: @user1494506:  Stereotypical examples of prvalue are 'true', '5', a non-reference return value of a function (these have the common property of having no 'identity' - no memory location). By contrast, a glvalue has 'identity'. Most glvalues are just ordinary lvalues (e.g. a local variable). The interesting case is a function which returns an rvalue reference, such as `static_cast<Class&&>` and `std::move`. Since it's a *reference*, it has an 'identity' (memory location), but it is nevertheless to be treated as shortly eXpiring - its contents can be reused - so it is classified as an 'xvalue'.

Comment: thanks!!

I took a quick look at std::move implementation, an in fact it is static_cast<Class&&> ;)

is it only possible xvalue?

Answer (score 4):

```
Class && rvr = Class();
```

What I'm going to say isn't going to make sense, but this is the C++11 rule.

`rvr` is a variable that is an rvalue reference to a `Class`. That's easy to understand. But it is important to understand this: a named variable is never an rvalue expression. ***Even if it is an rvalue reference!***

Again, I know that doesn't make sense, but that's the rule. An rvalue reference variable is *not an rvalue expression*.

A temporary is an rvalue expression, so `Class()` gives you an rvalue. The temporary returned from a function is also an rvalue expression, so if you had some function that returned `Class` by value, you would get an rvalue back.

This matters because if you have two functions overloaded based on lvalue and rvalue references (like copy/move constructors/assignment), C++11 will select the rvalue reference version *only* if the expression type is an rvalue.

This is why `std::move` exists. It exists to explicitly state when you want to move something. It does this by converting the value you give it into an rvalue expression. Namely, it returns `Class&&`.

This is the part that's really confusing. If you have a named rvalue reference variable, that isn't an rvalue expression. But if you have an *unnamed rvalue reference*, such as returning `Class&&` from a function, *that is an rvalue expression*.

`std::move` returns `Class&&`. So if you want to move from a named variable, you must *always* call `std::move` on it. So if you want to move from `rvr`, you must do this:

```
object = std::move(rvr); // (*)
```

This will return a `Class&&` to `rvr`. C++11 overload resolution will happen. Since the parameter to `operator=` is an rvalue expression, it will select the rvalue reference version of `operator=`. Thus invoking a move.

Note that `std::move` is really just a wrapper around a semi-complex cast. It doesn't do the moving; it's the `operator=` that does the moving.

Comment: so why `object = *(&rvr);` also calls copy operator=? Shouldn't `*(&rvr)` create "rvalue expression", the same way `std::move(rvr)` does?

Comment: @user1494506: No. Taking a pointer (which is what `&rvr` is: a `Class*`) and referencing it with `*` *always* returns an lvalue reference. There's no such thing as a `Class&&*` or a `Class&*`.